# joda-time import stopped working in Spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jodatime

I'm trying to test some code in the Spark shell (spark v. 1.3.0, using Scala version 2.10.4) and in the past was able to import joda-time libraries like this:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
```

Today when I started the shell on my local machine, I'm getting:

```
scala> import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
<console>:19: error: object joda is not a member of package org
       import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
                  ^

scala> import org.joda.time.DateTime
<console>:19: error: object joda is not a member of package org
       import org.joda.time.DateTime
                  ^

scala> import org.joda.time._
<console>:19: error: object joda is not a member of package org
       import org.joda.time._
                  ^
```

As far as I know nothing's changed overnight. Anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: It worked _in the shell_ before today? Or in an application? Are the joda-time libraries on the exact classpath that the shell is using today?

Comment: Worked in the shell prior to right now without providing any additional details.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why I'm getting inconsistent behavior, but this seems to fix it.

```
spark-shell --jars ~/jars/joda-time-2.8.1.jar
```

Comment: So your classpath was wrong? Did you manually update it before and only lose your changes when you logged out. perhaps?

Comment: Nope, and I never set it. Previously it just worked.

Comment: Hmm. _something_ changed! No idea what, though